# Used to vs. Would

Tags: grammar

According to Practical English Usage, "We use *used to*, not *would*, to talk about regular and important habitual behaviour.

Robert **used to** play a lot of football. (NOT *Robert would play* ...)

I **used to** smoke. (NOT *I would smoke* ...)"

I don't understand why *used to* can't be replaced with *would* in the examples above since they express the idea of *repeated actions* to which both *used to* and *would* can refer to.

By the way, what does ***important habitual behaviour*** exactly mean?

Comment: @Cardinal: Thanks for your comments. I went through that page before asking my question but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: "Would" can in certain contexts be used to indicate a serial state, as in _Whenever he heard his parents coming home, he **would** quickly put out his cigarette_.

Comment: @BillJ I said that earlier, but for some reason I deleted my comment. In fact, I think if there is a clear time reference, we can use **would** and "used to" interchangeably. "when I was a college student, I would smoke". Am I right?

Comment: @Cardinal You're right; once you establish the time frame is in the past, they become interchangeable.

Comment: @Cardinal They are not necessarily  interchangeable, since the meaning can be different, and often it becomes ungrammatical. In your example, "would" does not mean the same as "I used to smoke".

Comment: @BillJ I see. I should have said, "we can use would".

Comment: @BillJ 7: Can you explain about the difference in meaning, please?

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

- *Would* could lead the listener/reader to believe there's an *if* coming up or in context that may have been missed.  If you say the time, this is mitigated.

*Used to* doesn't hook into any *if* unless explicitly expressed.

> Robert used to play a lot of football.
>
> Robert would play a lot of football. [*If* ... something possibly?]
>
> Back in 1980 Robert would play a lot of football. [No *if* expected]

Problem 2:

- *Would* does not imply  that Robert isn't playing football anymore.  This is  part of the meaning of *used to*.

> In 1980 Robert would play a lot of football.  (He might still play football)
>
> In 1980 Robert used to play football.  (He does something else now)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do we know that "Robert might still play football" now? Because as far as I know "would" is used to talk about typical actions or or activities during a period IN THE PAST. So how do you relate it to the present?

Comment: Right, so if you say "X would Y", it only tells us what he was doing in the past, and doesn't tell us anything about the present without additional information.   Whereas "X used to Y" strongly implies X is not doing Y now without additional information.